# How to remove the highlight state of button in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have created button animations but i want it to show just the normal, pressed and disabled animation clips. Do You Have any idea how we can achieve this.

**When The Cursor Goes over it should keep playing the "normal animation clip".**

Comment: So why not make the setting of normal equal to highlight?

Comment: it starts the whole normal animation from start. i want the normal animation clip to keep playing even if hovered

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your Button Settings look similar to this example and that you have created all the needed animations for your button with the correct names.

In this example the Button plays the Normal animation when the player highlights as well. You could also add the Normal animation to the Selected Trigger or just let it empty (or don't create the animation with that specific name)

**If you just wan't to keep playing the Normal Animation let Highlighted and Selected empty**

[image: Button Settings]

Comment: But this just Starts the whole Normal animation again. Is there a way so that the Normal animation keeps playing even if hovered.

Comment: As mentioned in this answer: Did you try to simply leave it empty?

Comment: leaving it empty has the same results as writing Normal in that place.